# Fourier transform of an L1 function - Stein and Shakarchi, 2.25

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

This is from Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis (2.25). I'm really not so sure what to do with the hint. Can someone please walk me through the steps? I'm a little lost... thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be given by

$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty  e^{-\pi (t+|x|^2/t)}t^{\varepsilon-1-d/2}\,dt$$

where $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\varepsilon>0$.  Applying Fubini's Theorem, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x)|\,dx&=\int_0^\infty \underbrace{ \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}e^{-\pi |x|^2/t}\,dx\right)}_{=O(t^{d/2})} t^{\varepsilon-1-d/2}e^{-\pi t}\,dt\\\\
&=O(1)\int_0^\infty e^{-\pi t}t^{\varepsilon-1}\,dt
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $\varepsilon>0$, $f\in \mathbb{L}^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ as was to be shown.

---

The Fourier Transform, $\hat f$, of $f$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
\hat f(\xi)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x) e^{-i2\pi \xi x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left(\int_0^\infty  e^{-\pi (t+|x|^2/t)}t^{\varepsilon-1-d/2}\,dt\right) e^{-2\pi i\xi x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty t^{\varepsilon-1-d/2}e^{-\pi t}\underbrace{\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{-\pi |x|^2/t}e^{-i2\pi \xi x}\,dx\right)}_{=t^{d/2}e^{-t\pi |\xi|^2}}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-\pi |\xi|^2 t} t^{\varepsilon-1}e^{-\pi t} \,dt
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

Finally, enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto x/(\pi(1+|\xi|^2))$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\hat f(\xi)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-\pi x (1+|\xi|^2)}x^{\varepsilon-1}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\left(\frac{x}{\pi(1+|\xi|^2)}\right)^{\varepsilon-1}\,\left(\frac1{\pi(1+|\xi|^2)}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\pi^{-\varepsilon}\Gamma(\varepsilon)\frac1{(1+|\xi|^2)^\varepsilon}
\end{align}$$

as expected again!